# Select multiple non-consecutive files in Nautilus using only the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

My workflow relies almost a 100% on the keyboard. Therefore I would like to be able to select multiple non-consecutive files in Nautilus using only the keyboard. I know that:

- I can select multiple consecutive files pressing down shift at the first item and the go down with the arrow keys until the last item.
- I can select multiple non-consecutive files pressing down ctrl and clicking on each desired item with the mouse.

I would like to replace the mouse-clickings with something easy on the keyboard...any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you keep holding down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and press <kbd>space</kbd> you can move around with the arrow keys and select no consectuive files. Only downside of that, at least for me is, i dont have a file selection when moving and have to count the files, but that can be the case that im using an pretty old Laptop.