# Multiple file selection in list view

Tags: nautilus

I have found that using the shift or Ctrl keys in combination with the mouse does not work for selecting multiple files in Nautilus list view on 14.04. I have seen numerous posts stating that this works. I have also seen posts suggesting that compviz is involved. However these posts are all 6-10 years old and I would like a modern answer that will allow me to do multiple selection in list view.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple selections can be achieved via clicking on a file and using <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Arrow Up (or Arrow Down)</kbd>.

As shown in [Select multiple non-consecutive files in Nautilus using only the keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/q/755127/295286)  , it is possible to make non-consecutive selection via holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> , press <kbd>Space</kbd> once , and use mouse to select multiple files. Note: this is only active while you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Once you let go, non-consecutive selection becomes inactive.

Non-consecutive selection can be used with both list and icon view. Below is example with icon view

[image]

Comment: The user is already indicating that he knows how it works but it is not working for the version he uses. Explaining how it should work does not seem helpful.